# PHP object is null after initialization

Tags: php, class, object

I have the class file:

```
class Settings
{
public $siteName;
public $siteAddr;
public $dbUrl;
public $dbName;
public $dbPass;

public function __construct()
{
$siteName = 'Welcome';
$siteAddr = 'http://site.com';
$dbUrl = 'test';
$dbName = 'base';
$dbPass = '123';
}
}
```

Trying to use it in other file:

```
require_once('settings.php');
$cfg = new Settings();
var_dump($cfg); // <--- everywhere is null...
```

Why does it contain only nulls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$siteName = 'Welcome';
```

you need

```
$this->siteName = 'Welcome';
```

otherwise you just created variables in scope of your constructor, not initialized object members.

Answer (score 0):

The variables you're using in your constructor are local scope variables. To refer to class fields use `$this->fieldname`.